# Use Strapi to manage a list of 301 redirects on the frontend

Tags: nuxt.js, middleware, strapi, http-status-code-301

I have a Strapi (v4) backend and a Nuxt (v2) frontend, all the content is fetched using REST and GraphQL. Each environment runs on a different server and domain (provider is Digital Ocean)

My client wants to use Strapi to manage a list of 301 redirects (including regex), that is applied on the frontend.

So a visitor can be redirected from `www.site.com/old-url` to `www.site.com/new-url` while Strapi runs on `backend.site.com`

I'm not sure how to approach this. I'm currently using middleware in Nuxt to make redirects, but could I use ajax to fetch a list of redirects from Strapi? This would slow down every request. Could I make some sort of script that fetches the redirects from Strapi and saves it to a JSON file that the middleware could use? That might work, but is seems not very elegant.

Is there a better solution that I'm overlooking?

Comment: This could probably be solved properly at the hosting level IMO. Like Netlify redirects (hardcoded but easily editable). Or at the server too. I suppose then that you don't need any client-side redirects since 301 are only done on the server.

Comment: @kissu I'm currently hosting at DigitalOcean, switching to a different provider would be a lot of work, and I rather don't have to force my client to log in to the hosting panel to edit redirects. Nuxt can run redirects serverside, I'm already doing that using middleware.

Comment: No better solution here so. I mean, doing that at Nuxt's server level is good enough and has only the drawback of needing to wait for the build time. At the end, your client is probably not adding 10 redirects per day haha.